# DevExpress Dock panel below an inherited Windows Forms panel

Tags: .net, winforms, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I have a base form with a panel that creates a header for my form (with the app logo and some info). 
When I add a Dock panel using the DockManager in a form that inherits this base form, the Dock panel is added above the header panel.

How can I place the top Dock panel below this header panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Dock Panels must be docked to their container's edges before other controls. For this, the Dock Manager changed panels' z-index so that a panel has higher priority in docking. The only controls that have priority over Dock Panels are listed in the [DockManager.TopZIndexControls](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsDockingDockManager_TopZIndexControlstopic) collection. Thus, when the panel's z-index becomes lower than indices of other controls, the Dock Panel is positioned behind them. So, if your specific control should be always positioned close to the form's edges, you should add a string containing your control's type name into the [DockManager.TopZIndexControls](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsDockingDockManager_TopZIndexControlstopic) collection.